# Center align multi line html text to textview

Tags: android, textview, android-styles

I have the following html code I want to set to my TextView. I want the second line to be center aligned.Even after adding the left padding I don't see the text being aligned to the center.

```
String title = "<span style='font-family:Avenir Roboto Regular; font-size:16pt'>Howdy doing.<br></span><span style='font-family:Roboto Regular; font-size:16pt'>Doing great:</span>"


if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
        textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(title, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY));
    } else {
        textview.setText(Html.fromHtml(title));
    }
```

Comment: use `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` in the `TextView`.

Comment: You want only the second line of text to be centered ? If so, using 2 TextViews is probably the solution.